# how to clip content beyond a certail scroll point

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind. In the code snippet below, I have a sticky  component. I want all other content to disappear when scrollING past this sticky section. I am using a background and I want the content to disappear so I can see the  against the background with no content behind it.
(Currently, they just go behind the sticky part and it looks messy!)

```html
<div className="container mx-auto flex flex-col">
  <NavBarTitle />
  <div className="sticky top-16 z-20 self-center">
    <NavBarButtons />
  </div>

  **//CONTENT BEYOND THIS POINT SHOULD DISAPPEAR AS I SCROLL//**

  <div className="grid max-w-6xl grid-cols-1 py-6">
    <AlphabeticBlock>
      <Intro />
      <Projects />
      <Contact />
    </AlphabeticBlock>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</div>
```